# Regex in django query is throwing InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')

Tags: python, django

Query1: `Model.objects.filter(slug__istartswith="dfe")`

This is working fine in the shell.

while

Query2: `Model.objects.filter(slug__regex="^dfe")`

This is throwing Error,

`InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')`

What could be the issue?

Traceback:

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    697                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    698                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 699             printer.pretty(obj)
    700             printer.flush()
    701             return stream.getvalue()

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    401                         if cls is not object \
    402                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 403                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    404 
    405             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    701     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    702     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 703     output = repr(obj)
    704     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    705         if idx:

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __repr__(self)
    230 
    231     def __repr__(self):
--> 232         data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
    233         if len(data) > REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE:
    234             data[-1] = "...(remaining elements truncated)..."

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __iter__(self)
    254                - Responsible for turning the rows into model objects.
    255         """
--> 256         self._fetch_all()
    257         return iter(self._result_cache)
    258 

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in _fetch_all(self)
   1085     def _fetch_all(self):
   1086         if self._result_cache is None:
-> 1087             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
   1088         if self._prefetch_related_lookups and not self._prefetch_done:
   1089             self._prefetch_related_objects()

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __iter__(self)
     52         # Execute the query. This will also fill compiler.select, klass_info,
     53         # and annotations.
---> 54         results = compiler.execute_sql()
     55         select, klass_info, annotation_col_map = (compiler.select, compiler.klass_info,
     56                                                   compiler.annotation_col_map)

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scooby/plugins/sql/plugin.pyc in execute_sql(self, *args, **kwargs)
     40 
     41     if not threadlocal.sql_plugin_data:
---> 42         return self.execute_sql_default(*args, **kwargs)
     43 
     44     try:

/django_myrepo/apps/django_patches/apps.pyc in execute_sql_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    129     close_connection_if_required(connection)
    130     try:
--> 131         return self.default_execute_sql(*args, **kwargs)
    132     except (OperationalError, ProgrammingError) as e:
    133         if e.args[0] in (

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in execute_sql(self, result_type)
    833         cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    834         try:
--> 835             cursor.execute(sql, params)
    836         except Exception:
    837             cursor.close()

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
     77         start = time()
     78         try:
---> 79             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
     80         finally:
     81             stop = time()

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
    497             hub, self.cursor, sql, params, paramstyle="format", executemany=False
    498         ):
--> 499             return real_execute(self, sql, params)
    500 
    501     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
     62                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     65 
     66     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     92                 if dj_exc_type not in (DataError, IntegrityError):
     93                     self.wrapper.errors_occurred = True
---> 94                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
     95 
     96     def __call__(self, func):

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
     62                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     65 
     66     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
    108         try:
    109             # args is None means no string interpolation
--> 110             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
    111         except Database.OperationalError as e:
    112             # Map some error codes to IntegrityError, since they seem to be

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
    172             del tb
    173             self.messages.append((exc, value))
--> 174             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    175         self._executed = query
    176         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()

/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc in defaulterrorhandler(***failed resolving arguments***)
     34     del cursor
     35     del connection
---> 36     raise errorclass, errorvalue
     37 
     38 re_numeric_part = re.compile(r"^(\d+)")

InterfaceError: (-1, 'error totally whack')
```

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question and details about the DB you are using and the driver you are using to access it?

Comment: Added the traceback

Comment: What is going on in `/django_myrepo/apps/django_patches/apps.pyc`, are you manually handling connections/cursors? This error seems to be caused by connections either not being closed properly or trying to use a closed connection

Comment: But the same issue should happened with the first query as well. Right??